# How do we express "to put the tube or roll of paper into the beg vertically"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

When you put a roll of paper or a tube of something into a bag, it is a good idea to **put it in vertically** as the above picture because the tube may be too long that won't fit in the bag if **you put it in horizontally**.

How do we express "**to put the tube or roll of paper into the beg vertically**"?

For example, **put the tube / roll of paper in the bag upright**.

Answer (score 3):

"Vertically" or "upright" are synonymous here and both are acceptable.

You could also say "stand it up" or "don't lay it down"